# Does ICS allow port forwarding?

Tags: windows, networking, firewall, port-forwarding, ics

How can I open ports on a shared network using internet connection sharing (ICS)? I have forwarded the ports in the Advanced Settings, windows firewall, disabled security applications, forwarded on my router, netsh portproxy, and tried PassPort port forwarding utility, all without success.

If this is possible, could somebody explain how to correctly forward a port for an ethernet device connected to my Wi-Fi adapter using ICS?

Example:
[image: advanced settings]

Result:

Ethernet
[image]

Wi-Fi
[image]

Random ports are being used instead of 3074.

Comment: What’s wrong with the remote port not being 3074? That’s to be expected. /edit: Just noticed the direction, it’s outgoing. There should be no need for any port forwarding at all. Port forwarding is for *incoming* traffic.

Comment: @DanielB I am receiving a moderate NAT type on my Xbox that I am trying to forward through ICS. I have added an image of the Wi-Fi adapter traffic, and they're using different ports.

Comment: Yes of course. The local endpoint of the connection would use a random port from the [dynamic port range](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929851/the-default-dynamic-port-range-for-tcp-ip-has-changed-in-windows-vista). This is controlled *exclusively* by the application (Xbox firmware). What you’re seeing is *complete normal*  and *expected behavior*. There is nothing wrong except Xbox networking being an incredible pile of misinformation.

Comment: Please add information about your entire network to the question. You may need to set up additional port forwarding on your “real” router.

Comment: @DanielB I figured it may be something to do with Xbox itself, but surely the NAT type would be open if 3074 was correctly forwarded. My router is currently using UPnP, though I am seeing no active connections on 3074 via UPnP. I have also forwarded 3074 in the router firewall to my laptop on 192.168.1.141.

Comment: @DanielB I am unsure if UPnP conflicts with manual forwarding? And if I should be using the DHCP address assigned by ICS or my laptop's address in the ICS Advanced Settings NAT/forwarding?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63914/discussion-between-mrtod-and-daniel-b).